# sitecore logging (Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error) and Log record GUID

Tags: sitecore, log4net, sitecore7, sitecore8, log4net-configuration

I have question about sitecore logging:
When unexpected error happen I want to return to user unique ticket id, so when user will email about this error it could be found into logging database.

I've added **activity_id** parameter to SQL appender :

```
<param name="Parameter">
        <param name="ParameterName" value="@activity_id"/>
        <param name="DbType" value="String"/>
        <param name="Size" value="400"/>
        <param name="Layout" type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%P{activityId}"/>
        </param>
      </param>
```

Now, I need to add **activityId**. Normally I would do it like this :

```
private void Application_Start()
{
...
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("activityId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

How can I do it into SiteCore Logging ? 
so I can use:

Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error happen", this);

**Update:**
I've added following code to Global.asax.cs , and value is still empty.

```
public class Global : Sitecore.Web.Application
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            log4net.MDC.Set("activityId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore logging is based on log4net. Idea is to transfer your value into log4net context. You can try:

```
log4net.MDC.Set("activityId", "value");
```

from Sitecore.Logging assembley

Comment: Is there specific requirements where should I add this code ? I've added this code to Global.asax.cs and value still empty (I added update to original post).

Comment: I tried to  add this code right before logging, seems it has no effects on SiteCode.Diagnostics.Log and my activityId field still empty. I ended up by adding GUID to message text.It will be searchable by SQL LIKE statement.But still it would be good to have it into separated field.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the following code to write into the database:

```
//get your ID here - Example: 
var activityId = GetId();

Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(activityId, this);
```

This will be written into your database.